# R In SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, r, sql-server-2016

Trying to execute the test script that MSDN provides to make sure R is enabled, but it throws the following error,

```
Msg 39023, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_execute_external_script, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
'sp_execute_external_script' is disabled on this instance of SQL Server. Use sp_configure 'external scripts enabled' to enable it.
Msg 11536, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 1 result set(s), but the statement only sent 0 result set(s) at run time.
```

I have made sure i run the

```
Exec sp_configure  'external scripts enabled', 1
```

Reconfigure  with  override

Statement and then i made sure the configuration setting was set to 1 which it is, and restarted the services inbetween checking and afterwards, but no luck.

I've also made sure i'm not side loading any other R open platform ide's or other versions of SQL Server versions except 2016 developer.

Comment: Please provide the output of `sp_configure 'external scripts enabled'`.  Are you sure you have restarted the instance successfully?  For example, if you attempt to restart the SQL Server service from Management Studio it will pop up an "Are you sure ... ?" box.  Try stopping and starting the service via services.msc just to be sure.

Answer (score 6):

Run:

```
Exec sp_configure  'external scripts enabled', 1;
reconfigure;
```

Then restart the service from `services.msc` or restart your system.

Answer (score 2):

Just restart the SQL Server from 'Services' or restart from Sql Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `RECONFIGURE;` after executing `sp_configure 'external scripts enabled', 1;` query before restarting the server.